# After Combining Tor to Firefox

Tags: firefox

After combining Tor to Firefox (as is an option, when you already have Tor downloaded) 'Tor' is no longer visible within "programs".

That being said, how does one 'remove' Tor from being a part of Firefox, thus, leaving it on its own terms, thus visible within your "programs" features?

Comment: how exactly you have combined them? It's a two different processes/programs/binaries - they can not be combined, actually...